# Spout is not reading/emitting data in storm cluster mode

Tags: apache-storm

I am using apache storm 1.0.0 both in local as well as cluster mode. For the spout, I am reading the data from kafka topic (I am using kafka 2.11-0.8.2.1). Spout is reading the data from kafka topic and also emitting the data when I am using storm in local mode but the storm spout is not emitting any data when I am running storm in cluster mode.

**My topology implementation for reading kafka data is as follow:**

```
brokerHosts = new ZkHosts(kafkaZookeeper);
SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts, kafkaTopicIn, "", "storm");
kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout", new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig), 2);
```

**My storm configuration file (conf/storm.yaml):**

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
- "localhost"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]

storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm"
```

I am also not getting any error while submitting Storm topology in cluster mode.

Any idea why topology spout is not emitting any data in cluster mode ??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As your steps, i don't see you started nimbus, supervisor, UI before submitted topology to production/cluster mode, then verify this cluster in storm UI, also check log file if got any errors.

Please share this information.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting topology to cluster u need to start nimbus and supervior.
If that is done u will find logs folder in storm. You can check log files from there and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable suggestion.
It's working now. There was some issue with the log4j logger API version that I was using with storm-1.0.0 topology. This log4j was not causing any issue in local mode but was causing the issue in cluster mode.

Comment: @user2720864: I was integrating the storm 1.0.0 with Elasticsearch and Kibana 5.2.2. But the problem was that log4j version used by storm 1.0.0 was not compatible with Elastic and Kibana. so I manually updated the log4j in storm's library folder. In short, the issue was not with my storm configuration but it was with the version of Kibana and elastic search I was using.